# Change devise default root

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

My root page is a welcome page that has a link that opens a sign up modal.

I have specific pages that needs authentication. When I go to that specific page I am redirected to localhost:3000/users/sign_in. But I want to redirect the user to my home page and show the modal. I mean that I want the sign in page to be localhost:3000/ and somehow , just in that case passing a parameter that allows me to know that I have to open the popup.

I mean,
When I go to localhost:3000 I should just show the home screen.

But If I go to localhost:3000/myspecificpagewithauthentication I should be redirected to localhost:3000?showsignup=true  (in order to be able to show the modal using JS) and after sign up I should be redirected again to localhost:3000/myspecificpagewithauthentication (already authenticated).

I am using Devise and RoR 3.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

devise is a well documented gem. [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-when-the-user-can-not-be-authenticated) you go

**update:**

to change after sign in path, write your own after_sign_in_path_for method to application controller. This will override devise's method.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  your_custom_path
end

end
```

Comment: This is very useful. Thanks. Now I am able to redirect to my root, but I need to know if I come from localhost:3000/myspecificpagewithauthentication or localhost:3000. Is that possible?

Comment: What I need to do is to redirect the user to localhost:3000/myspecificpagewithauthentication after authentication. How can I do that?